# Why child component not mounted?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component

Why child component not mounted?

Base template:

```
<TableComponent :data="data">

      <template slot="thead">
        <tr>
          <TableHeader></TableHeader>
        </tr>
      </template>

</TableComponent>
```

`TableComponent`:

```
<template>

  <div>
    <table>
      <thead>
      {{ renderThead() }}
      </thead>
      <tbody>

      </tbody>
      <tfoot>

      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>

</template>

<script>

  export default {
    name: 'TableComponent',

    props: {
      data: {
        required: true,
        type: [Array, Function]
      },
      itemKey: {
        default: 'id',
      },
    },

    methods: {
      renderThead: function () {
        let method = this.$scopedSlots.thead
          ? this.$scopedSlots.thead
          : () => this.$slots.thead

        console.info(method())

        // return method();

      },
    },

  }
</script>
```

It is `TableHeader` component :

```
<template>

  <th>
    {{ name }}
  </th>

</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'TableHeader',

    props: {
      name: {
        type: String
      }
    },

    mounted() {
      console.info("MOUNTED")
    }
  }
</script>
```

Console info on `TableHeader` not working.
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You have to show your parent component, as the mounting of the child component depends on that.

Comment: @BennettDams , what do you mean?

Comment: The "mounted" function will be executed as soon as your `TableColumn` is mounted at the page. But as your `TableColumn` is a child component of `TableComponent`, it's mounting depends on the `TableComponent`. Therefore you need to post your `TableComponent` code or the place you're using it.

Comment: @BennettDams I updated the code.

Comment: Are you importing and registering the `TableHeader` component in your "base" component? (Or, equivalently, are you registering it globally?

Comment: @StephenThomas , yes. I importing `TableHeader` in base component like `  import TableHeader from './Table/TableHeader'` and include it on `components` like `components: { TableHeader }`.